# WCF Service best practice to keep my services alive

Tags: c#, wcf, servicehost

I have several WCF Services in my WPF application, I open them using this method:

```
private void StartSpecificWCFService(IService service, string url, Type serviceInterfaceType)
{
    ServiceHost serviceHost = new ServiceHost(service, address);
    serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(serviceInterfaceType, new NetNamedPipeBinding(), url);
    serviceHost.Open();
    //sign to serviceHost.Faulted ??
    _wcfServicesHolder.Add(serviceHost); //A dictionary containing all my services
}
```

the services attributes are:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
```

The services are logging service  and event service, they get many calls from other processes.. I use namedpipes since it is the fastest and the processes run on SAME computer.

My question is - How do i maintain these services to be up all time ?

1. Poll timer that iterate  _wcfServicesHolder and check if service is opened
2. sign to serviceHost.Faulted event.

And after a service is in faulted state, does the client (on different process) must be re-created ? or it can still broadcast message on same channel ?

The exception i receive is:

```
There was no endpoint listening at net.pipe://localhost/LoggingService that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details
```

Comment: Host them in IIS (or in a Windows service) instead of in your WPF application.

Comment: Is your WPF application running all the time?  Are your ServiceHosts dying or is the problem that they haven't been created yet when the service gets called?

Comment: They are created and opened when WPF application starts, the WPF application runs all the time.

Comment: @zimdanen i cant host the services on IIS/Windows service. this is how architecture was designed.. not ATM

Comment: You can host your services separately in Windows OS....but with IIS also they should be always alive...."There was no endpoint listening at..." this error can also occur if there was some error while initializing your service and your services have not been loaded...write a logging code around your ServiceHost snippet to find out..

Comment: @SutharMonil thanks for resp, the services been loaded properly they stop working after a while, probably due to exception being thrown and not catch on service side..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do the services have `InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single` with concurrent thread access?  Do the services hold some kind of in-memory thread-safe state?  If not, it may be well worth trying to re-factor the services to use `InstanceContextMode.PerCall`.  This should be your default and preferred choice when configuring WCF services - WCF is primarily a technology for implementing a service-orientated architecture, and using a mode other than `PerCall` violates the Statelessness principle of [SO Design Principles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service-orientation_design_principles).

In support of this, if you have a server-side fault with `InstanceContextMode.Single`, this suggests something has gone seriously wrong in the service.  Any state that you maintained within the service will be lost - clients can not expect just to re-connect and resume as normal.

Whatever `InstanceContextMode` you end up using, your channel will fault if it remains open with no clients connecting to it for a certain length of time.  Over TCP (or any protocol that explicitly exposes a reliable session), you can specify the inactivity timeout on the reliable session, but you have no such option using pipes.

With pipes, leaving a channel open longer than the configured timeout, will fault the channel rendering it useless.  You can subscribe to the channel faulted event, and recreate the proxy if you are interested in keeping a channel open to the service for the lifetime of your application.  As you suggest - another option is to keep polling along the channel to keep it alive.

Comment: Would the service respond to incoming requests faster if it didn't have to spin up a new instance per call?

Answer (score 1):

In order to keep your service host up, go with your #2 option (Subscribe to the faulted event on the service host).  When faulted, you need to Abort the servicehost, new up a fresh instance, rewire the faulted event handler, and open the service host.

There's not much official documentation on this scenario, but here's an old post from an msdn blog describing what you're looking for.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/drnick/archive/2007/01/16/restarting-a-failed-service.aspx

As to the client, it also will need to recreate its channel to the server when said channel is faulted.